# Is there any Example of XMLWorkerHelper in C#

Tags: asp.net

I want to use the followingd code in c#. What dll i need to ad to my project so that the following code can work.

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, 
 new FileOutputStream(new File("./target/test-classes/examples/columbus2.pdf")));

doc.open();

HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext();

htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

CSSResolver cssResolver = 
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(true);

Pipeline<?> pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, 
    new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext , new PdfWriterPipeline(doc, writer)));

XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);

XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);

p.parse(XMLWorkerHelperExample.class.getResourceAsStream("columbus.html"));

doc.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it's code for the [iText PDF Library](http://itextpdf.com).

It's F/OSS software that can be [downloaded here](http://www.itextpdf.com/download.php) or directly from [SourceForge here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/itextsharp/).

From there, you'll include their library's DLL in your project and you'll be good to go!